# I deleted my firebase firestore collections manually and created the collections again but i can no longer read from one of the collections

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I had 2 collections and I deleted them to start afresh but I can't seem to retrieve data from the other collection yet I can retrieve data from the other collection. I created both of them manually.
this is my database.
[image: database]

this is my the method i described in my apiservice

[image]

this is the method definition
[image]

Comment: What is not working exactly? Are there any errors while reading data from one of those collections ?

Comment: What is the code that you are using for reading the collections? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: the query actually runs but it returns an empty array yet there are records matching that query

Answer (score 1):

solved...
the get  method was by ordering by a missing value "timestamp" which is not part of fields in the job so i added the the timestamp field